# How to structure local imports in main.py to allow for testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, module, package

I am trying to test my application. I have a very standard project structured like so:

```
root
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── logic
│       └── calc.py
├── tests
│   └── test_main.py
│
└── pyproject.toml
```

My main.py makes use of a class from the `logic/calc.py` file, and looks something like this:

```
# app/main.py

from logic.calc import Model

def main() -> None:
    m = Model()
    print(m.some_attribute)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can run `python app/main.py` and it'll work great. The problem occurs during testing:

```
# tests/test_main.py

from app.main import main

def test_main():
    assert main() is None
```

Running `pytest` will result in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logic'`. The import in `main.py` is going wrong!

So we can fix this by adjusting the import to `from app.logic.calc import Model`. The test now runs smoothly. However, now I cannot run `python main.py` anymore! This will result in an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. So this seems like a Catch-22.

#### Installing the package

Installing the project as a package using `pyproject.toml` solves this issue, as the `app` module now becomes available everywhere. However, I would prefer not to install the package, as I am packaging the project in Docker, and package installation has some effects that I am trying to avoid.

**Can I get both direct execution and tests working at the same time, *without* installing the project as a package?**

It seems like a basic problem, but somehow I haven't been able to find answers or figure it out. Help much appreciated!

Comment: A workaround is to run the unit tests in a separate package. This not only fixes the relative dependencies, but also allows the unit tests to be run in batch rather than on a per-file basis.

Comment: Thanks for the input. After thinking a bit more about how namespaces work, I think the desired result as described in my post isn't possible. I ended up installing the package anyway, and running my main as `python -m app.main`.